# Selenium: Element is not clickable at point (x, y)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I try to click several elements in a list, which works fine for the first few elements:

```
xp = "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp)
element.click()
```

With every click, the list expands and the elements below drop. Once the next element to click is gone from my screen, I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (135, 887)
```

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: Some other element is potentially overlaying the desired element and is intercepting the clicks.  You should investigate what that element is and why it is blocking it.

Comment: I think it's not overlayed. It's just not visible on the screen anymore. If I scroll down manually, I can see the element.

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait  Then you potentially need to do a wait until on the element to be clickable

Comment: No this is not the issue. Imagine you have a list of elements. if you click on element 1, a dropdown menu will open below element 1. This leads to a drop of element 2. Before clicking on element 1, element 2 was located like 10 cm below the top of my screen and after clicking element 1, element 2 is located 20 cm below the top of my screen. Then if you click element 2, element 3 will drop aswell and will be gone from the window. As a human you would scroll down now, to see element 3 again to click it.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes clickable links embedded in buttons. So you should look clickable sites or buttons in button's html code. achievements